# Extracting time difference and then summing them up with gmtime()

Tags: python, tuples, python-datetime, micropython

I'm trying to find ways to calculate the difference of time measurements taken at different intervals, and then sum them up. Since datetime is not available in MicroPython, I tried gmtime() function and  successfully extracted the difference of time measurements taken in different intervals. like this:

```
from utime import time, gmtime, sleep

start = time()
sleep(5)

while True:
    delta = gmtime(time() - start)
    print(str('%02d:%02d:%02d'%(delta[3:6]))
    sleep(1)
```

This gives me time difference in a nice HH:MM:SS format. But I'm stuck at summing values in the same format. Since gmtime() produces 8 value tuples and tuples can't be added, I can't find a way to do it.

Sure I can do it like:

```
from utime import time, gmtime, sleep

while True:
    #if something happens, measure time here:
        measurement = time()
    #otherwise wait...
    #if another condition is met measure the difference here:
        delta = time() - measurement
        total = total + delta #then keep summing the total amount of time passed, in between measurements.
    print(total)
    sleep(1)
```

But this'll just be an integer of seconds, not in full HH:MM:SS time format.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "summed time differences."  Can you provide a simple example?  i.e. if I had a time measurement from ten minutes ago, one from five minutes ago, and one from right now, what would the summed difference be of those three measurements?

Comment: I updated my second code, please take a look. Hope it cleared things a bit.

Comment: So, keep all your sums as floating point values.  Only when you need to present the result to a human being should you convert it to the string format.  Also, you don't need `datetime` -- the `time` module has `strftime`.

Comment: You can use timestamp of current time and convert it to anything you want.

Comment: So it looks like `total` is an amount of seconds.  So is your question really "Given an arbitrary number of seconds, how can I display that nicely in hour:minute:second format"?

Comment: Haha masterfully simplified and worded sir. "total" actually keeps all the differences between two measurements of time(). Since time() returns a big integer, incrementing since 1st Jan of 1970. So "total" can be any arbitrary integer, depends of the interval of the measurements: 100, 458, 6957... you get the idea. I want to take multiple measurements and save the total amount of time pased in between those measurements in HH:MM:SS format.

Comment: No.  You want to KEEP the total amount of time as floating point seconds.  You want to PRINT those measurements in HH:MM:SS format.  The difference is important, and commonly missed.

Comment: How can I store it in floating point seconds and how can I print it in HH:MM:SS format? Using strftime you mentioned earlier?